# Kernel Panic when booting Citrix XenServer 6.5 on Dell PowerEdge 1850

Tags: dell-poweredge, xenserver

A clean installation of XenServer 6.5 results in a kernel panic when installed on a stock build Dell PowerEdge 1850 with 16GB DDR2 RAM and 3.0Ghz Irwindale Xeon with Hyperthreading. Kernel Panic documented in [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Ugbzsk_g94)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [documented bug](https://bugs.xenserver.org/browse/XSO-195) in 6.5 will prevent booting on older, HyperThreaded CPUs. The workaround is to disable "Logical Processors" (Hyperthreading) in the Dell PowerEdge 1850 BIOS, which will allow you to boot without panic.

Comment: If you mark this as answered, it will remove it from the unanswered list.  The answered question will remain for future reference.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it seems there is some sort of a minimum time limit on when I can accept my own answer. Stack Overflow is telling me I can accept and answer tomorrow. I've made note of it and will do so then.